# Sixaxis (PS3 Controller) doesn't work correctly connected with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, steam, gamepad, ps3

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 64-bits.

While on Steam, I noticed a peculiar behavior. If my Sixaxis is connected with a USB cable, everything works fine, but if connect it through Bluetooth either games don't recognize it or the inputs are weird (SELECT becomes X)

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe try to use sixad: https://askubuntu.com/a/913600/139248

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might try it out. I can't believe that in 2017 we still have to compile bluetooth drivers to get them to work correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to also have a sixaxis controller, and originally had your same problem.

When the device is plugged in USB mode, it behaves as expected, and most games will recognize it as the correct device. On Bluetooth, it works under a different spec, which most games don't support very well on Linux.

The basic problem here is that when the controller is on USB, it is registered to the Linux kernel as a HID device with all it's codes such as product and manufacturer IDs. This allows games to quickly and accurately identify the controller and load it's configs.

When you connect it via bluetooth, whichever bluetooth driver you are using attempts to connect the device as a HID via the Xserver or userspace desktop manager. This obscures much of the information about the device from the game or application, and since Linux support is commonly left in the dust compared to Windows, the game devs or engine don't spend the time to add this level of compatibility since it's not very well standardized.

### The Fix/Workaround:

Easy:
Since the "joystick" to the game is now a virtual device instead of a USB one, they will be recognized as completely different devices. If the game supports it, you could add the custom config with the remapped controls to the game.

Medium:
You can remap the joystick controls via a handy gui, perhaps `jstest-gtk`, `jscalibrator` or `jscal` may work. You could also try other non-official tools to remap the joystick, although I have yet to find any which work perfectly over bluetooth.

Difficult:
The `xboxdrv` could be used to remap the controller to Xbox, though this solution probably [isn't the easiest](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xboxdrv.1.html).
Another solution would be to look into other Bluetooth drivers (though I don't recommend this) that have better support. Personally, I've found the program `blueman` to be extremely useful without having to reinstall bluetooth drivers.

Hope my experience helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The easy way works sometimes, but not in all games unfortunately. The remapping has some problems, for example I click one button and it detects the up and down as two buttons. The Difficult I have yet to try, maybe `blueman` is the best solution.